# Using a field of view in the view's sub query

Tags: mysql, sql-view

I have a view which has a column which is calculated from other columns. For example, in my original table I have the columns `A` and `B` from which I calculate the value of column `X` in my view. I need the value of `X` in another column I have in the view - `Z`. But when I put it in the sub-query of my view I get an `Unknown column 'X' in 'field list' SQL statement`.

The sub-query of the view looks like this:

```
    (CASE
            WHEN (`users`.`A` REGEXP '^(regexone)') THEN 'ValueA'
            WHEN (`users`.`B` REGEXP '^(regextwo)') THEN 'ValueB'
            ELSE ''
        END) AS `X`,
    (CASE
            WHEN
                (`X` = 'ValueA')
            THEN
                (`users`.`C`*0.95-0.3)
            ELSE ''
    END) AS 'Z'
```

What's the correct syntax of using a computed view field in the computation of another field?

Comment: You cant do this way and need to have the logic inside the 2nd case as `case when  case WHEN (users.A REGEXP '^(regexone)') THEN users.C*0.95-0.3 else '' end end`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty So I need to repeat the calculation everywhere I need this field?

Comment: Thats correct or if you use subquery then you can use that on the outer query. `select x.aa from ( select aa from table )x`

Comment: I'm not sure what's the syntax of incorporating that into a view

Answer (score 0):

if you can you user-defined variables use like

```
SELECT
@x := (CASE
        WHEN (`users`.`A` REGEXP '^(regexone)') THEN 'ValueA'
        WHEN (`users`.`B` REGEXP '^(regextwo)') THEN 'ValueB'
        ELSE ''
    END) AS `X`,
(CASE
        WHEN
            (@x = 'ValueA')
        THEN
            (`users`.`C`*0.95-0.3)
        ELSE ''
END) AS 'Z'
```

Comment: got this error: `View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter`